# Custom formats on TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I need your help about custom formats on tinymce.

I replaced the default formats with custom classes :

```
tinymce.init({
    formats: {
        h1: {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'head1'},
        h2: {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'head2'},
        h3: {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'head3'},
        h4: {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'head4'},
        h5: {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'head5'},
        h6: {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'head6'},
 },
```

But if I select a word and I click on "Format 1" then "Format 3", result is :

```
<span class="head1 head3">my words</span>
```

I would like format3 to replace format1 like that :

```
<span class="head3">my words</span>
```

I did not find anything in the documentation that allowed me to do it.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking to do is counter-intuitive to the rest of the formatting buttons in place. If you press the `bold` button, and then the `italic` button, the bold formatting is not overwritten, it's only added to.

The same goes for any custom formatting. You'll need to deselect `head1` for it to disappear from the class list of your span.